# Translate Java SOAP Request to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, soap

I'm working on making a SOAP request in Javascript. I've never done a SOAP request before, and the service provider only has sample code in Java.

Here's their Java sample code:

```
    String applicationPath = "c:\\e-Notify\\";
    String inputDirectory = "inputs\\";
    String outputDirectory = "outputs\\";
    String url = "https://example.com/ENotifyService.svc";  
    String xml = "";
    String resp = "";
    String action = "";
    String inputFilePath = "";
    String outputFilePath = "";     
    try {
        //Encode the URL
        URL urlx = new URL(url);
        //Instance of connection object
        HTTPRequestPoster poster = new HTTPRequestPoster();         
        //Character stream
        Reader data = new StringReader("");

        //Get the XML from the input file
        inputFilePath = applicationPath + inputDirectory + "manage-consultant-list-input.xml";
        xml = FileReader(inputFilePath);
        data = new StringReader(xml);
        //Set operation
        action = "ManageConsultantListRequest";
        //Send request to server and get the response.
        poster = new HTTPRequestPoster();
        resp = poster.postData(data, urlx, action); <==NOTE `ACTION` VARIABLE
        //Write the response to the output file
        outputFilePath = applicationPath + outputDirectory + "manage-consultant-list-output.xml";
        FileWriter(outputFilePath, resp);           
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Per sample code provided by the SOAP API owner, I need to send the following values:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <ManageConsultantListRequest xmlns="http://com.example.services.ServiceModel/2012/eNotifyService">
      <Credentials xmlns:a="http://com.example.services.ServiceModel/2012/Credentials" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:Username>MyAPIUsername</a:Username>
        <a:Password>MyAPIPassword#1</a:Password>
      </Credentials>
      <Consultants xmlns:a="http://com.example.services.ServiceModel/2012/eNotify" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:Consultant>
          <a:SubmissionActionCode>A</a:SubmissionActionCode>
          <a:Jurisdiction>IL</a:Jurisdiction>
          <a:LicenseNumber>00000001</a:LicenseNumber>
        </a:Consultant>
      </Consultants>
      <TransactionID>12345</TransactionID>
    </ManageConsultantListRequest>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I'm looking at the [npm Soap package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap#handling-xml-attributes-value-and-xml-wsdloptions).

```
import soap from 'soap'; //https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap

let url = 'https://example.com/ENotifyService.svc';
let args = {name: 'value'};
soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
    client.MyFunction(args, function(err, result) { <==WHERE TO PUT DATA FROM `ACTION` VARIABLE??
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

I think I can **probably** get the XML data I need into JSON format using something like the technique described at https://davidwalsh.name/convert-xml-json.

I haven't yet figured out:

- How to get the data contained in the Java `action` variable, into the npm soap package call. It doesn't seem to have a place for it. ???

Thanks very much in advance for any thoughts/advice/info!

**UPDATE:** If anyone would like to show how to do it using an alternative soap package, that would be an accepted answer as well!

Comment: I worked with SOAP services before, but I haven't used this particular client. However, browsing the documentation it seems that it expects a WSDL file which is a contract for the service rather than the service endpoint. The WSDL contain information on message formats and available services which the client can use to generate XML for you exposing a [method named after the service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap#clientmethodargs-callback---call-method-on-the-soap-service). If you just need to post and receive XML you can use a generic http client like axios instead.

Comment: Darn, I meant to say the method is named after the action. Once you generate a client from the WSDL you should be able to call `client.ManageConsultantListRequest(args)`

Comment: @patonw, what soap client do you use?

Comment: @patonw, could you post an answer showing how you would handle this in the soap client you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually **paid** somebody on UpWork to help me figure this out! Neither of us could figure out how to get the npm `soap` package to work on this API. However, he provided this alternative approach, which did work:

```
var request = require("request");
var rawXML = ''; //your xml goes here
var options = { method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://example.com/eNotifyService.svc',
    qs: { asmx: '' },
    headers:
        { 'cache-control': 'no-cache',
            Connection: 'keep-alive',
            'content-length': '1960',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            Accept: '*/*',
            'User-Agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.15.0',
            Host: 'example.com',
            SOAPAction: '"requestedAction"',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
            'Content-Type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8' },
    body: rawXML };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);

    console.log(body);
});
```